# How to get a list of Flask application routes on a webpage

Tags: python, flask

I have a flask application written in Python3.6.x that lives in a docker.

When I have the docker container for the backend up and running, I can do **FLASK_APP='run.py' flask routes** to get a list of all the endpoints in the application within the shell.

What changes should I make to get that entire list as a web/html page??

Comment: Difficult to answer unless you tell us *why* you want that. [This is *potentially* helpful with what you're looking for but hard to say for sure](https://swagger.io/specification/v2/#:~:text=Swagger%E2%84%A2%20is%20a%20project,generate%20clients%20in%20various%20languages.)

Comment: @JaredSmith The idea is to form a basis for api automation tests. There are more than 600 end-points and 0 api automation tests. So, having a document will ease the testing task management

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What changes should I make to get that entire list as a web/html page??

I'm guessing you want the output of `flask routes` available within a your own route, so you can then render this, by passing it to a template or something...

See where the [`flask routes` command is implemented](https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/660994efc761efdfd49ca442b73f6712dc77b6cf/src/flask/cli.py#L894-L900) and how this grabs the data...

```
def routes_command(sort: str, all_methods: bool) -> None:
    """Show all registered routes with endpoints and methods."""

    rules = list(current_app.url_map.iter_rules())
    if not rules:
        click.echo("No routes were registered.")
        return
```

So to implement this in your own program, you could do the same:

```
from flask import Flask, current_app

app = Flask(__name__)

# Just another demonstration route for the output.
@app.route('/some/route/<withParam>')
def some_route(withParam): return 'success'

@app.route('/')
def index():
    rules = list(current_app.url_map.iter_rules())
    
    if not rules: 
        return 'No rules defined'

    def get_dict(rule):
        return { 'endpoint': rule.endpoint,
                 'methods': ','.join(rule.methods),
                 'rule': rule.rule }

    output_list = [get_dict(r) for r in rules]

    print (output_list)

    return 'success'
```

`output_list` is a list of dictionaries which looks like:

```
[{'endpoint': 'index',
  'methods': 'GET,HEAD,OPTIONS',
  'rule': '/'},

 {'endpoint': 'some_route',
  'methods': 'GET,HEAD,OPTIONS',
  'rule': '/some/route/<withParam>'},

 {'endpoint': 'static',
  'methods': 'GET,HEAD,OPTIONS',
  'rule': '/static/<path:filename>'}]
```

Obviously in the above sample I've just printed this to the terminal, but now that you have this in a python data structure, it's easy enough to pass this via `render_template` and display it in page.